# The action 'destory' could not be found in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I think I'm losing it. I can't figure out why a simple destroy link wont work all of a sudden.

I'm getting this error:

AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /plans/v41w74v2
The action 'destroy' could not be found for PlansController

Plan Controller:

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index
  @plans = Plan.all
end
def new
  @plan = Plan.new
end
def create
  @plan = Plan.new(plan_params)
  if @plan.save
    if @plan.trips.empty?
      @possible = @plan.group.trips
      render "add_trips"
    else
      redirect_to plans_path, notice: "Plan successfully created"
    end
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
def show
  @plan = Plan.find_by_unique_identifier(params[:id])
end
def edit
  @plan = Plan.find_by_unique_identifier(params[:id])
  @group = @plan.group
  @possible = @plan.group.trips
  render "add_trips"
end
def update
  @plan = Plan.find_by_unique_identifier(params[:id])
  if @plan.update_attributes(plan_params)
    redirect_to plans_path, notice: "Plan successfully updated!"
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
def add_trips
  @plan = Plan.find_by_unique_identifier(params[:id])
  trip.each.update_attributes(plan_id: @plan.id)
  redirect_to plans_path, notice: "Trips added to plan"    
end
def destory
  @plan = Plan.find_by_unique_identifier(params[:id])
  @plan.destroy
end
```

Plan show View:

```
<%= button_to "Delete", @plan, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this plan?"} %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep. You've got a typo. `destory`.